# Como posso reduzir essa função? (Problema Simples)

Tags: javascript

Codigo:

```
<body>
 <div name = 'numeros' id = 'n1'>14</div>
 <div name = 'numeros' id = 'n2'>14</div>
 <div name = 'numeros' id = 'n3'>14</div>
</body>

<script>

 var numeros = document.getElementsByName('numeros')

 function reiniciar(){
   n1.innerHTML = ''
   n2.innerHTML = ''    //Dúvida
   n3.innerHTML = ''
 }
</script>
```

Meu objetivo é com uma ou duas linhas de código, trocar todos os valores dentro de 'numeros' por ' ' (tudo isso dentro da function reiniciar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o forEach na lista de núemros:

```
var numeros = document.getElementsByName('numeros')
function reiniciar(){
    numeros.forEach(function(n){
          n.innerHTML = '';
     });  
 }
```